# React Navigation- How to Navigate to a specific index in a Datasource

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, navigation, react-navigation

I am brand new to React Native, and I'm trying to create a simple recipe app. I have the app functioning properly right until I need to navigate to a specific recipe from my dataset. I'd like to have a singleRecipe.js component that I can just pass the data and index into, and once the user click on that recipe item in the list view, it navigates to the correct data.

I have seen this done on NavigatorIOS but I can't quite figure out how to do it on the new React Navigation. Any help I would really appreciate.

Here is my Recipe List View file:

```
class RecipeScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
    this.state = {
      dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(RecipeListData)
    };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ListView
          dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
          renderRow={(RecipeListData) => <RecipeListItem {...RecipeListData} />}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

RecipeListItem.js

```
const RecipeListItem = props => (
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={Actions.singleRecipe}>
    <View style={styles.container}>

      <Text>
        {`${props.name}`}
      </Text>
      <Text>
        {`${props.time}`}
      </Text>

    </View>
  </TouchableOpacity>
);
```

This is the single recipe page I am looking to pass the data into.

```
class SingleRecipe extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {/*// This is a single recipe I need to fill with the data from DataSource*/}
        <Text>
          This is a single recipe!
        </Text>

      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

My very basic data set:

```
export default RecipeListData = [
  {
    "name": 'Breakfast Burritos',
    'time': "90 Minutes"
  },
  {
    "name": 'Peanut Butter Chicken',
    'time': "30 Minutes"
  },
  {
    "name": 'Sweet Potato Mash',
    'time': "20 Minutes"
  },
  {
    "name": 'Korma Curry',
    'time': "45 Minutes"
  },
  {
    "name": 'Protein Smoothie',
    'time': "20 Minutes"
  },
]
```

Comment: @AdamPatterson I have found a similar app that uses IOSNavigator with an onPress function on the list item.

 `_onGoToRecipeButton: function(rowData){
    this.props.navigator.push({
      title: rowData.name,
      component: Recipe,
      rightButtonTitle: 'Share',
      onRightButtonPress: () => this._onShareButton(rowData),
      passProps: {
        recipe: rowData
      }
    });
  }, `

 I made a mistake when asking the question, I am actually using react-native-router-flux. But have not been able to find a way to implement this in rnrf.

Comment: Are you able to pull data from `RecipeListData` and put it into a `singleRecipe.js` component?

Comment: How does the app function right now, what works and what doesn't work?

Comment: Do you want the user to click on a single recipe in the listview and then navigate to singleRecipe.js, along with the data and index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try: `Actions.singleRecipe({ data: rowData })`

Then at SingleRecipe.js you should be able to access it like: 
`<Text>{this.props.data.name}</Text>` or `<Text>{this.props.data.time}</Text>`

Comment: No I don't think it's a typo, `singleRecipe` is the key I set up on the router. I was able to pull the `RecipeListData` for the data in the list view. But when you click on an item in the list view, it just goes to a `SingleRecipe` component without the data passed through. I need to share the `RecipeListData` props with the `SingleRecipe` page. But like you said in your last comment, I'd like it to correspond with the data and index of the ListView item selected.

Comment: I looke more closely, edited my answer. Didn't initially  realize that was a key.